# What code can I use to download a csv file that requires some steps after logging in to the website?

Tags: python

After some research on my problem, it seems I should use either `requests` or `urllib` or both.

So basically, I am trying to learn the code I need to download a csv file from this url:

https://globalaccess.sustainalytics.com/#/tools/0

The way I manually download my files is as follows: first, I need to log in using username and password. Next I have to go to a tab called "Screening" that takes to me another page that has several buttons called "Generate". I click a specific generate button (it's always the same one) among the option to get the excel file. After that I have the option to save the file or open from a little window within the website.

My question is what code can I use on Python to download and save the file in a particular folder?

Comment: you can use requests/urllib to send HTTP request to serve and get HTTP response from sever - one of response will send file. Or you can use `Selenium` to control web browser.

Comment: Welcome to [so], while I can understand you, please read about what's on topic in our [help/on-topic] and read about [ask]. If you have a specific problem we're happy to help but what you're looking for is a guide / tutorial and for that I'd suggest to use google, try something and come back to ask more specific questions.

Answer (score 1):

Use Selenium

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

You'll need to download a 'chromedriver' to the same directory as your python script, then use the intro tutorial on the selenium docs site to drive the browser to type/click where you want.

If you use chrome you can right click on any given link/input box click inspect, then in the window that comes up right click the bit of highlighted code and 'copy xpath'.  Use the find element by xpath function in Selenium to send keys or clicks to that element.